# Magento 2.2.5: How to console.log() in js file

Tags: magento2, javascript, debug

I'm trying to debug a js file in Magento 2. And I don't know how to do that. I've try console.log('something in here') but doesn't work, I've clear cache as well.

Here is my problem:
I've 3 checkboxes here, and they count in that"input hidden" in the image below.
[image]

So when I click on the checkbox to turn off, it counts down 1 (see the image below). It works perfectly til here.
[image]

But when I click on the checkbox again. It should count up 1 right, but it doesn't. I don't know where is wrong in my code.

Here is my js file named assign-slide.js (this js is following assign-product.js):

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\adminhtml\web\catalog\category\assign-products.js

```
/**


* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/* global $, $H */

define([
    'mage/adminhtml/grid'
], function () {
    'use strict';

    return  {
        assignSlide: function(config){
        var selectedSlide = config.selectedSlide,
            bannerSlide = $H(selectedSlide),
            gridJsObject = window[config.gridJsObjectName],
            tabIndex = 1000;

        $('in_banner_slide').value = Object.toJSON(bannerSlide);

        /**
         * Register Banner Slide
         *
         * @param {Object} grid
         * @param {Object} element
         * @param {Boolean} checked
         */
        function registerBannerSlide(grid, element, checked) {
            if (checked) {
                if (element.positionElement) {
                    element.positionElement.disabled = false;
                    bannerSlide.set(element.value, element.positionElement.value);
                }
            } else {
                if (element.positionElement) {
                    element.positionElement.disabled = true;
                }
                bannerSlide.unset(element.value);
            }
            $('in_banner_slide').value = Object.toJSON(bannerSlide);
            grid.reloadParams = {
                'selected_slide[]': bannerSlide.keys()
            };
        }

        /**
         * Click on Slide row
         *
         * @param {Object} grid
         * @param {String} event
         */
        function bannerSlideRowClick(grid, event) {
            var trElement = Event.findElement(event, 'tr'),
                isInput = Event.element(event).tagName === 'INPUT',
                checked = false,
                checkbox = null;

            if (trElement) {
                checkbox = Element.getElementsBySelector(trElement, 'input');

                if (checkbox[0]) {
                    checked = isInput ? checkbox[0].checked : !checkbox[0].checked;
                    gridJsObject.setCheckboxChecked(checkbox[0], checked);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Change Slide position
         *
         * @param {String} event
         */
        function positionChange(event) {
            var element = Event.element(event);

            if (element && element.checkboxElement && element.checkboxElement.checked) {
                bannerSlide.set(element.checkboxElement.value, element.value);
                $('in_banner_slide').value = Object.toJSON(bannerSlide);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Initialize Banner Slide row
         *
         * @param {Object} grid
         * @param {String} row
         */
        function bannerSlideRowInit(grid, row) {
            var checkbox = $(row).getElementsByClassName('checkbox')[0],
                position = $(row).getElementsByClassName('input-text')[0];

            if (checkbox && position) {
                checkbox.positionElement = position;
                position.checkboxElement = checkbox;
                position.disabled = !checkbox.checked;
                position.tabIndex = tabIndex++;
                Event.observe(position, 'keyup', positionChange);
            }
        }

        gridJsObject.rowClickCallback = bannerSlideRowClick;
        gridJsObject.initRowCallback = bannerSlideRowInit;
        gridJsObject.checkboxCheckCallback = registerBannerSlide;

        if (gridJsObject.rows) {
            gridJsObject.rows.each(function (row) {
                bannerSlideRowInit(gridJsObject, row);
            });
        }
    }};
});
```

EDIT 1:

So I found the way to debugging with `console.log` if you go to `pub/static../your_js_file_that_you_want_to_console_log.js` and put `console.log` in there and clear cache also `Ctrl + F5` in your browser so it clear your browser cache as well.

But my problem with js still there.

Comment: Please share your full code.

Comment: Oh, i've a bigger problem now, please check.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/238050/magento-2-2-5-how-to-set-checkbox-checked-with-grid-addcolumn
Thanks :)