# Magento 2.2.5: How to set checkbox checked with Grid addColumn()

Tags: magento2, multiselect

I have an issue here with the checkbox checked.
I've read a lot of solution, but they always say add the `'values' => array('something')`
I've followed that solution but nothing change. I've deploy again, but no use. The checkbox still not checked.
I've added the "checked" => true. But doesn't work too.

Here is my code and debug as well.

```
$this->addColumn(
            'in_banner',
            [
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'name' => 'in_banner',
                'values' => $this->_getSelectedSlide(),
                'index' => 'id',
                'checked' => true,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction'
            ]
        );
```

As you can see, i set `'values' => $this->_getSelectedSlide()`, so i'll bebug that function so you guys can see its an array like what they told me to.

[image]

Also, when i click on checked, it not render `checked = "checked"`.
[image]

EDIT 1:
I'm follow @kunj solution, but i dont think that's gonna work, because i'm doing after catalog_category_product and this is what i debug in they code. Its really dont have any difference.
[image]

So, i've try this but doesn't work, also i've run command di:compile, staic-content:deploy, setup:upgrade

```
$this->addColumn(
                'in_banner',
                [
                    'type' => 'checkbox',
                    'name' => 'in_banner',
                    'values' => [1,2],
                    'index' => 'id',
                    'checked' => true,
                    'header_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction',
                    'column_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction'
                ]
            );
```

EDIT 2:
Here is my code:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\Aht\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Tab\Slide.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * Slide in banner grid
 *
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
namespace Aht\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Tab;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended;

class Slide extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @var \Aht\BannerSlider\Model\SlideFactory
     */
    protected $_slideFactory;

    protected $_bannerSlideFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Aht\BannerSlider\Model\SlideFactory $slideFactory,
        \Aht\BannerSlider\Model\BannerSlideFactory $bannerSlideFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_slideFactory = $slideFactory;
        $this->_bannerSlideFactory = $bannerSlideFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('banner_slider_banner_slide');
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }

    /**
     * @return array|null
     */
    public function getBanner()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('banner');
    }

    /**
     * @param Column $column
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {
        $field = $column->getFilterIndex() ? $column->getFilterIndex() : $column->getIndex();

        if ($column->getId() == 'in_banner') {
            $slideIds = $this->_getSelectedSlide();
            if (empty($slideIds)) {
                $slideIds = 0;
            }
            if ($column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('id', ['in' => $slideIds]);
            } elseif (!empty($slideIds)) {
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('id', ['nin' => $slideIds]);
            }
        } else {
            parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Grid
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_slideFactory->create()->getCollection();
//            ->addFieldToSelect(array('id', 'name', 'image'));

//        check id vì 2 TH , add và update
        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('id')) {
            $this->setDefaultFilter(['in_banner' => 1]);

//            main_table được lấy tự động.
            $collection->getSelect()
            ->joinInner(['banner_slide' => 'banner_slide'], 'main_table.id = banner_slide.slide_id')
            ->where('banner_id = ?', $this->getBanner()->getId());

//            phải để addFilterToMap ở bên ngoài thì mới chạy được filter by created_at.
//            nó thay created_at = main_table.created_at
            $collection->addFilterToMap('created_at', 'main_table.created_at');
            $collection->addFilterToMap('updated_at', 'main_table.updated_at');
            $collection->addFilterToMap('id', 'main_table.id');
//            hiển thị câu lệnh sql:
//            echo $collection->getSelect();die();
        } else {
            $collection->addFieldToSelect('*')->load();
            $collection->getItems();
            $collection->addFilterToMap('created_at', 'main_table.created_at');
            $collection->addFilterToMap('updated_at', 'main_table.updated_at');
        }


        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Extended
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'in_banner',
            [
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'name' => 'in_banner',
//                'values' => $this->_getSelectedSlide(),
                'values' => ['1,2'],
                'index' => 'id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'id',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'sortable' => true,
                'index' => 'id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn('name', ['header' => __('Name'), 'index' => 'name']);
        $this->addColumn('url', ['header' => __('URL'), 'index' => 'url']);
        $this->addColumn('image', ['header' => __('Image'), 'index' => 'image']);

        $this->addColumn(
            'position',
            [
                'header' => __('Position'),
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'position',
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'created_at',
            [
                'header' => __('Created Time'),
                'type' => 'datetime',
                'index' => 'created_at'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'updated_at',
            [
                'header' => __('Last Update'),
                'type' => 'datetime',
                'index' => 'updated_at'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'action',
            [
                'header' => __('Remove'),
                'type' => 'action',
                'getter' => 'getId',
                'actions' => [
                    [
                        'caption' => __('Remove'),
                        'url' => [
                            'base' => 'banner/slide/remove'
                        ],
                        'confirm' => 'Are you sure?',
                        'field' => 'id'
                    ]
                ],
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable' => false,
                'index' => 'stores',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-action',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-action'
            ]
        );

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('banner/*/grid', ['_current' => true]);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getSelectedSlide()
    {
        // get slide position trong bảng banner_slide
        $slide = $this->getRequest()->getPost('selected_slide');
        if ($slide === null) {
            $slide = $this->getBanner()->getSlidePosition();
            return array_keys($slide);
        }
        return $slide;
    }
}
```

Its works wonderful, except the checkbox doesn't checked, and also, cant search with ID, but still can search with others (ex: name, image, url, created_at, updated_at).

In case you need more code:

Here is my template

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\Aht\BannerSlider\view\adminhtml\templates\banner_slide\banner\edit\assign_slide.phtml

```
<?php

/** @var \Aht\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\AssignSlide $block */

/** @var \Aht\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Tab\Slide $blockGrid */
$blockGrid = $block->getBlockGrid();
$gridJsObjectName = $blockGrid->getJsObjectName();
?>
<?= $block->getGridHtml() ?>
<input type="hidden" name="banner_slide" id="in_banner_slide" data-form-part="banner_form" value="" />
<script>
    require([
    'assign_slide'
], function (assign_slide) {
        assign_slide.assignSlide({
            "selectedSlide": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getSlideJson() ?>,
            "gridJsObjectName": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ '"' . $gridJsObjectName . '"' ?: '{}' ?>
        });
});
</script>
<!-- @todo remove when "UI components" will support such initialization -->
<script>
    require('mage/apply/main').apply();
</script>
```

The template call to a js file, but that doesn't matter with my problem right now, i thing, because when i remove this code in js file in `pub/static` , it still not checked in the checkbox.

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\Aht\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\AssignSlide.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Aht\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner;

//use Aht\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Tab\Slide;

class AssignSlide extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
    /**
     * Block template
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'banner_slide/banner/edit/assign_slide.phtml';

    /**
     * @var \Aht\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Tab\Slide
     */
    protected $blockGrid;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $registry;

    protected $_bannerSlideFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface
     */
    protected $jsonEncoder;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        \Aht\BannerSlider\Model\BannerSlideFactory $bannerSlideFactory,
//        Slide $blockGrid,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
        $this->_bannerSlideFactory = $bannerSlideFactory;
//        $this->blockGrid = $blockGrid;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve instance of grid block
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function getBlockGrid()
    {
        if (null === $this->blockGrid) {
            $this->blockGrid = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \Aht\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Tab\Slide::class,
                'banner.slide.grid'
            );
        }
        return $this->blockGrid;
    }

    /**
     * Return HTML of grid block
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridHtml()
    {
        return $this->getBlockGrid()->toHtml();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSlideJson()
    {
        $slide = $this->getBanner()->getSlidePosition();
        if (!empty($slide)) {
            return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($slide);
        }
        return '{}';
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve current category instance
     *
     * @return array|null
     */
    public function getBanner()
    {
        return $this->registry->registry('banner');
    }
}
```

This AssignSlide.php file call the template out, which is assign_slide.phtml.

Comment: `'values' => [1,2,3],` must work you can refer from magento `Magento\User\Block\Role\Grid\User`.

Comment: well, i've doing after you, but doesn't work. do i have to deploy or something?

Comment: yes, try after di compile.

Comment: ok, i'll try it when i get home, and i will report the result for you later.

Comment: i've edited my post, please check :)

Comment: try with static array like [7,6]

Comment: wow, you know what, after i run di:compile, deploy and setup:upgrade, it still not working at all :)

Comment: Can you share your full code

Comment: yes, i'll update full code right now.

Comment: I've edited the post, please check :)

Comment: Dear this should be like this         'values' => [1,2],        not like this   'values' => ['1,2'],    because ['1,2'],       thi is like one string

Comment: tried 'values' => [1,2], still no work ... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after some help, i've found the answer.

 I trace after addColumn() function and realize it run into Checkbox.php

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\Checkbox.php

So i debugged in that checkbox.php and one again, i realize that my problem wasn't in the `'values' => [1,2]` or something, because the checkbox.php have this code :

```
public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
{
    $values = $this->_getValues();
    $value = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
    $checked = '';
    if (is_array($values)) {
        $checked = in_array($value, $values) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
    } else {
        $checkedValue = $this->getColumn()->getValue();
        if ($checkedValue !== null) {
            $checked = $value === $checkedValue ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
        }
    }

    $disabled = '';
    $disabledValues = $this->getColumn()->getDisabledValues();
    if (is_array($disabledValues)) {
        $disabled = in_array($value, $disabledValues) ? ' disabled="disabled"' : '';
    } else {
        $disabledValue = $this->getColumn()->getDisabledValue();
        if ($disabledValue !== null) {
            $disabled = $value === $disabledValue ? ' disabled="disabled"' : '';
        }
    }

    $this->setDisabled($disabled);

    if ($this->getNoObjectId() || $this->getColumn()->getUseIndex()) {
        $v = $value;
    } else {
        $v = $row->getId() != "" ? $row->getId() : $value;
    }

    return $this->_getCheckboxHtml($v, $checked);
}
```

As you can see, the `$values = $this->_getValues();` is return my array, which is pass through `'values' => [1,2]` stuff, and  `$value = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());` is pass through this code:

```
$this->addColumn(
        'in_banner',
        [
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'name' => 'in_banner',
            'values' => $this->_getSelectedSlide(),
            'index' => 'slide_id',
            'header_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction'
        ]
    );
```

Which mean `$values = [1,2]` and `$value = 1`, After that, it compare $value with $values and see if $value is inside $values or not, which mean 1 is inside array(1,2) or not. If it do inside, then "checked = checked" , else ..

So the point is what i've done wrong here is i has tranfer `id` of the `banner_slide` table, when it should be `slide_id` in `banner_slide` table.
[image]

And why am i do after catalog_category_product but my code doesn't work, its because i heard they use something called `entity`, `EAV`. Right now, i dont understand much about that, but i will find it out soon.

Thanks you all for reading and helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $this->addColumn(
>             'banner',
>             [
>                 'type' => 'checkbox',
>                 'name' => 'in_banner',
>                 'values' => $this->_getSelectedSlide(),
>                 'index' => 'id',
>                 'checked' => true,
>                 'header_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction',
>                 'column_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction'
>             ]
>         );
> ```

following code use to set checkbox on grid and 'values'  is use to get and by defult chekbox set selected in this code _getSelectedSlide() is use to send selected ids array pass to ***render()*** function.

so which checkbox you set selected this checkbox ids set in array and pass in '***values '***

> ```
> public function _getSelectedSlide(){
>     return array([0] => 20 [1]=>23 [2] => 32);
> }
> ```